# Under what conditions does ferric phosphate precipitate from solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, chemical-biology

I would like to know the conditions which cause ferric phosphate to precipitate from solution.

I am trying to culture iron bacteria, for which the culture media contain ferric citrate and phosphates, and my experience is that I persistently get a yellow precipitate which I believe is ferric phosphate.
Once the yellow precipitate has formed, the culture becomes inactive presumably because all the iron has been taken out of solution.

I assume that ferric phosphate precipitates above a certain pH, perhaps pH 7, but perhaps redox potential is also a factor, so I'm not sure, hence the question.

Update

My solutions typically contain the following things:

di-basic phosphate: 1.5 milli mole/litre
mono-basic phosphate: 0.2 milli mole/litre
ferric ammonium citrate: 25 micro mole/litre
(I always keep the pH around 7)

This didn't form a yellow precipitate when I first tried it, but does now.
Possibly because the iron precipitated out as ferric hydroxide so quickly that the ferric phosphate didn't have time to form.

Comment: What is the order of magnitude of the concentrations of Fe(III), of iron citrate and of phosphate ions ?

Comment: Under most conditions. Ferric phosphste is very insoluble. Citric complex with ferric ion may keep precipitation in check, kinetically and thermodynamically. The outcome very depends on ratio of all three components, together with pH. Provide details.

Comment: Is possible to use a citrate pH buffer instead of the phosphate one? or to provide more citric acid/citrate up to amount comparable to phosphate? As solubility of FePO4 is in order of 0.01 micromol/L, much less in presence of phosphate excess.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  Since iron reducing bacteria can apparently use iron in the form of ferric oxide or hydroxide, I am now trying that, since it seems to avoid the phosphate problem.